# Julia言語で小数点以下の有効数字の出力

Tags: julia

Julia言語で有効数字５桁を出力したいのですが、どのように出力すれば良いのでしょうか？
以下ではうまくいきません。

```
round(0.0625,digits=6)
#0.0625
```

この場合、欲しい値は0.062500です。
指定した有効数字に対して, ０以上の数値がない場合は０で補完するといった感じです。
このようなツール関数は存在するのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

他の一般的なプログラミング言語と同様に、`printf` で桁数を指定すればよさそうです。

質問の例に当てはめるなら、`@printf "%.6f" 0.0625` となりそうです。

**参考:**
[Printf - The Julia Language](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Printf/)

> Usage
>
> ```
> @printf([io::IO], "%Fmt", args...)
> ```
>
> Example
>
> ```
> julia> @printf "Decimal two digits %.2f" 1.23456
> Decimal two digits 1.23
> ```